# VS Code , Node Js Debugger Not working. Could Not find any debuggable target

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug nodejs code using Launch.json attach to process. I have tried following configuration
but debugger is not getting connected. my application is running on Node v6.11.5

Launch.json :--

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        
    }
```

,[Error getting displayed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqcX1.png)

Comment: How are you launching your node application, have you specified the `--inspect` flag before launching?

Comment: Yes I have , I am launching the application with gulp start command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gulp you can use a configuration like this to launch the gulp task from VSCode using the `Run`->`Start Debugging` `F5` command and debug it directly.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MyGulpTask",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "console": "internalConsole",
        }
    ]
}
```